# What i did wrong in this css?

Tags: html, css

In the below image please take a look at the **REQUEST FORM** (inside green background) , it's aligned over top, instead I need to align in centered vertically

[image]

**CSS style used ,**

```
.rtitle {
background-color: Green;
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 25px;
font-size: 30px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

*I need a exactly centered div style using css please help.*

Comment: you should provide the HTML too. it's hard to debug when you have no idea what the markup looks like.

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: [blog]: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top "There's a good answer here :)"

Comment: Rather pompeus to put this on hold when there are people who actually did spend time to answer the question.

Comment: Got solutions from others Answers. Anyway Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use your styling on a button it is in the center. It could be some other styling that you have that does this. Or something in your html.

```css
.rtitle {
background-color: Green;
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 25px;
font-size: 30px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="rtitle">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to fix this is add a padding-top in your style.

Comment: Thx . Yes padding-top and padding-bottom lines works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your CSS style:

```
button p {
margin: auto
}
```

And remove

```
text-algin:center
```

Plus the padding from `.rtitle` style and add your text between `<p> </p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, add a `line-height` equal to `height` to your class:

```css
.rtitle {
    background-color: Green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    line-height: 50px; /* ADD */
}
```

```html
<div class="rtitle">REQUEST FORM</div>
```

Works all the time for any font (unless you have meddled with `vertical-align`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the text inside into a span

Then on the span use

```
.span {top: 50%; position: relative; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zt31ra3k/